# Error: Non-static variable super cannot be referenced from a static context >>but i use static keyword

Tags: java, variables, static, super

How can i refers to "a1" from superclass (class "aa") with "super" keyword

```
class aa {
protected static int a1 = 2;
}

public class bb extendeds aa {
static int a1 = 3;
public static int s = super.a1;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a typo? `static in a1 = 3;`

Comment: Why do you want to alias `a1` as `s`? Why don't you just use `a1`?

Comment: `public static int s = aa.a1;` there is no way to access it with `super.a1` as long as you are in a static context

Comment: `super` is not a static context. You probably wanted to use `s = aa.a1;` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* want to use `super` instead of just doing `aa.a1`, you can *technically* do this in the constructor without error and only get a warning:

```
public static int s;

public bb(){
    this.s = super.a1;
}
```

**Test Run:**

```
aa a = new aa();
bb b = new bb();
System.out.println(a.a1);
System.out.println(b.s);
```

**Output:**

> 2
>
> 2

I really do not recommend doing this and try to avoid using `static` with objects or just use `static` like a `static` field if you really do need one.

Answer (score 1):

The `static` members of a class belong to a class and not to a particular instance.

When you invoke `super.member` you are trying to access the `member` of the current **instance** inherited from the parent class. It is done so because the same member might be shadowed in the child class, so `super` will refer to the member in the parent class.

So in a `static` context it is ambiguous that from which *instance* the member is going to be initialised with a value. In fact static members can be accessed when no instances exist. So the usage of `super` in a static context (method or in your case a field) is not possible and the compiler throws an error.

Furthermore the static fields are initialised when the class is loaded at which point no instance variables are initialised. So initialising with `super.member` makes no sense.

From [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2):

> The form super.Identifier refers to the field named Identifier of the
>   current object, but with the current object viewed as an instance of
>   the superclass of the current class.

You need to modify your code to:

```
public class bb extendeds aa {
   static int a1 = 3;
   public static int s = aa.a1; //a1 belongs to class aa not to an instance
}
```